# Symfony 2 bundle dependency issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I created a bundle to manage user-group-permissions. I want it to make project independent by moving it into the vendors directory.
To make this bundle immutable I moved the users data into a usermeta bundle.
The main bundle contains username and email only about the user, and usermeta contains everything else (name, birthdate etc. whatever a project require).

The problem is the main user bundle intended to belong to a core bundle group, from which every project using the same.
The user-usermeta relation now created a dependency. So every project will need it.

My question is
 - How can I standardize its format, to enforce in every project create it properly.
 - How can I make this dependency optional (preferred)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you only handle a UserInterface instead of a User entity in your bundle.

In case of Symfony UserInterface doesn't implement everything you need (username but no email), create your own UserInterface in your bundle :

```
namespace YourDomain\YourBundle\Interface;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface as BaseInterface;

/**
 * UserInterface is the interface that user classes must implement.
 */
interface UserInterface extends BaseInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns the email address of the user.
     *
     * @return string The user email address
     */
    function getEmail();
}
```

And then, in the projects using your bundle, your User entity must implements your specific interface instead of Symfony UserInterface.

Comment: For the sake of completeness you can refer to the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html